# Calculate a function using the fact that is multilinear and alternant

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, discrete-mathematics

I'm currently working in the following excercise:

> Be $f$ defined in $\mathbb{R}^4 \times \mathbb{R}^4 \times \mathbb{R}^4 \times \mathbb{R}^4$ a function, calculate it in
>
> $$
>   \begin{pmatrix}
>     1\\
>     2\\
>     0\\
>     1 
>   \end{pmatrix},
> \begin{pmatrix}
>     3\\
>     2\\
>     4\\
>     0 
>   \end{pmatrix},
> \begin{pmatrix}
>     0\\
>     1\\
>     7\\
>     2 
>   \end{pmatrix},
> \begin{pmatrix}
>     1\\
>     6\\
>     3\\
>     1 
>   \end{pmatrix}
> $$
>
> Using the fact that $f$ is multilinear and alternant

How could I calculate a function without knowing it? Also I've tried to play with the information provided but is not too clear to me how the fact that $f$ is multilinear and alternant helps. Thanks in advance for any hint or help and for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: Honestly, the only thing that I could think of was showing that the vectors are linearly dependent, which would imply that the image is $0$. However, they're not as the determinant of the $4\times4$ matrix is $131$ and not $0$. So I have to ask, did you copy the values correctly?

Comment: Notice that the fourth vector can be rewritten as a linear combination of the first three

Comment: How would you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show that $f=\lambda\det$ for some $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$. Then compute the determinant.

Comment: How would you figure out what $\lambda$ should be? Is there even sufficient information?

Comment: There isn't, $f$ is multilinear and alternate whatever is $\lambda$. The most you can do is to express the solution depending on $\lambda$.